# How to Disable and Enable selection for a item in QListWideget using Python

Tags: python, pyqt

hi guys im going a tools using a listwidget to list of objects to update some function.
so the user select any no of item in list and perform a function.. once it done then that updated item should disable selection mode how to achieve this in PyQt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query the selected items:

```
items = listWidget.selectedItems()
```

And set the flags for these selected items to `Qt.NoItemFlags`:

```
for item in items:
    item.setFlags(Qt.NoItemFlags)
```

This way you can disable the selection of the items.

Comment: Thanks qurban.. then how to get all the items from a list?